# Prove that to any three numbers positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove that for any three  positive integers, following equality holds $$\operatorname{lcm}(ab , bc , ca ) \cdot \gcd(a , b, c )=abc$$

Comment: Please read again and edit. Language not making much sense

Comment: What is "$Icm$" ? Did you mean "$\textrm{LCM}$" ?

Comment: Sorry man about the language, I wasn't focus,

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392250/prove-or-disprove-statements-about-the-greatest-common-divisor

Answer (score 2):

By the Unique Factorization Theorem, it is enough to prove the result for integers $a, b, c$ which are each powers of a prime $p$.

Let $a=p^\alpha$, $b=p^\beta$, and $c=p^\gamma$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $0\le \alpha\le \beta\le \gamma$.

Then $\text{lcm}(ab,bc,ca)=p^{\beta+\gamma}$ and $\gcd(a,b,c)=p^\alpha$, so the product is $p^{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}$. This is equal to $abc$.

Answer (score -1):

If
$$gcd(a,b,c) = k  $$
Then
$$LCM(ab,bc,ca) = abc/(Factors\text{ } shared \text{ } by \text{ } abc)$$
Since if you multiplied $ab$ by $c$ and $bc$ by $a$ and $ca$ by $b$ then it is easy to see that $abc$ is a common multiple of $(ab,bc,ca)$.
It may not be the lowest common multiple since the numbers we multiplied by might have been redundant by having common factors i.e. $gcd(a,b,c)$
$$(Factors\text{ } shared \text{ } by \text{ } abc) = gcd(a,b,c) = k$$

Comment: @RossMillikan You are correct, I edited my answer to account for that.